# iOS status bar overlap

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms to build an iOS app.
I've got the following structure:

```
- navigation page
-- tabbed page
--- content page
---- listview
--- content page
```

The result is the following:

[image]

How can I solve that. 
I know that there are quite a few duplicates but these are for xcode. I need it for xamarin forms?

**I don't want to hide the status bar.
I just want to status bar at the top and the bounds of the app right below. 
Setting the padding of root navigation page to 0,20,0,0 did not work.**

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ServiceLocator.Instance.Add<ICloudService, AzureCloudService>();
            var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(Pages.MainPage.Instance);
            navigationPage.Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);

            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(Pages.MainPage.Instance, false);

            MainPage = navigationPage;
        }
 }
```

UPDATE:
I've also tried this one:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ServiceLocator.Instance.Add<ICloudService, AzureCloudService>();
    var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(Pages.MainPage.Instance);
    Pages.MainPage.Instance.Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);

    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(Pages.MainPage.Instance, false);

    MainPage = navigationPage;
}
```

Comment: Your image isn't working. Also show us some code or XAML as to how you create your layout. The padding thing should work.

Comment: I've added a code snippet.

Comment: Because you are not showing the NavigationBar anymore, you probably want to set the padding to your page which is in the `Pages.MainPage.Instance`.

Comment: i think you need to add margin in order to do this.

Comment: try to add this line your plist : <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>

Comment: well, i don't want to hide it @KKRocks.

Comment: the result stays the same @GeraldVersluis

Comment: can you understand objective c ?

Comment: I've never used objective c. But UIStatusBarHidden = true means hide the status bar. Isn't it?

Comment: There seems to be something weird going on, because it seems the padding of 20 is added on the bottom, there is a whitespace in your screenshot. I think you need to have a good look at the pages you are creating and how it all fits together.

Comment: I think you need to add padding in the content page rather than navigation page. Try that it will solve your problem

Comment: see update. I've already tried to apply it to the tabbedpage. Shouldn't that be enough?

Answer (score 1):

You should set padding in ContentPage not NavigationPage